# Where do synchronised objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

We have a parent BU already connected to SF-CRM-1

We have created a child BU and need to connect this to SF-CRM-2 (different instance)

The parent BU synch'ed DE's show up in the synchronised data extension folder.

I want to know how and where the sync'ed objects show after i connect the new BU to SF-CRM-2.

Will they sync into the same folder?

What if they are called the same name across both CRM instances e.g. Account_Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to log a support ticket in Salesforce Help to enable [Marketing Cloud Multi-org](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_upgrade_to_multi-org.htm&type=5). Hence you can connect the new salesforce instance to your child BU.

To set up the synchronized DE you can read this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5).

Once you enable the Marketing Cloud Multi-org and connect the 2nd Salesforce instance to the child BU, it will use the synchronized data from the 2nd Salesforce instance.

Synchronized DEs always locate in Synchronized Data Extension folder.

The synchronized DE names from your child BU will have the same name e.g. Account_Salesforce, Contact_Salesforce,...

Comment: If an object is already synchronized from SF-CRM-1 then it will get a numeric suffix when it will also be synchronized from a different SF org. For Example `Account_Salesforce_1` for the new org while the it will remain as `Account_Salesforce` for SF-CRM-1

Comment: Thank you @RafałWolsztyniak, I was telling him in the context that he was going to connect the child BU with his 2nd SF instance. Also in case, connecting 2 BUs to a same SF instance by the same API user will result with the same synchronized DE name